# How to add manual payout on stripe NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

actually I am very good at NodeJS but I have never tried manual payout in stripe NodeJS and after browsing through internet a lot I am facing difficulty to understand.
In my app there is customer who pays for ride and I've already created route for payment where I process payment from customer.

```js
const customer=await stripe.customers
      .create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        source: req.body.stripeToken,
        address: {
          line1: '510 Townsend St',
          postal_code: '98140',
          city: 'San Francisco',
          state: 'CA',
          country: 'US',
        },
      })
      console.log(customer)
    if(customer){
      const charge=await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: req.body.amount * 100,
        currency: "USD",
        customer: customer.id,
        description: "Crowdshipping Customer Payment 2",
        source: req.body.source.id,
        receipt_email:req.body.email
      })
```

Now my boss asked me to add manual payout to send this money to driver who took ride. How can I add manual payout to send this money to driver?. A little guidance please!

Comment: Hello, have you looked at the example docs for this already? They have snippets you can use. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of work with payments, commissions and payouts should be, in this case, Stripe Connect is suitable for you, where you can study the necessary functionality and understand what you need from there
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33098150)